# How to prevent someone access the database without permit

Tags: c#

my application ( C#+SQL server) is running on the shared hosting. However, someone is able to access the database without permit. The connection string in the Web.config file, it had also been encrupted. Based on the above the senario, I have the following questions:

1. Is the shared hosting not secure?
2. Is the coding not really secure?

If the problem on the coding, what should I fixed? Many thanks!

**------In Web.config, before encrypt------**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyLocalSQLServer" connectionString="Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;
Data Source =192.07.32.45; Initial Catalog =myDataBase; User Id =Username; Password =Password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

***------In Web.config, After encrypt------****

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="MyUserDataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: share your code that do the connection stuff

Comment: And you need to provide more details of how the person is able to access the database.  Using your application?  Using SQL Server Management Studio?  Something else?

Comment: Point 1 is a question that should be asked to your hosting company.

Comment: They decrypted the connectionstring and find the database location, username and password there.

Comment: How do you know somebody has access to your database?  If you have data that you really need to protect, shared hosting isn't what you should be using, because you cannot limit who can access the content.

Comment: @Acubi - Sure its possible.  What is a local network address.  They would need to know the domain for the SQL Server was in order to access your database.  How do you know this happen?

Comment: @Ramhound, someone access to the database and add scripts every week.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that

- your database connection string is set in your application's configuration file `web.config`
- the connection string is encrypted - details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

It also makes sense to use a password generator create the user credentials, or a use long phrase (such as "[correct horse battery staple](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase)") as the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing unauthorized access to your database despite your `web.config` data being encrypted, then it's entirely possible that your database itself was compromised.

Most shared SQL providers allow remote connections, so someone could have brute-force attacked or otherwise compromised your database.

There are a number of best practices for securing a database, including:

- Disable the SA account and create another user account to manage the database, or
- Rename the SA account.
- Use [strong passwords](http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/) or, as Jeremy McGee mentioned, [long-phrase passwords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19982/how-to-prevent-someone-access-the-database-without-permit/19983#19983).
- Use separate users with limited, specific access according to role.

  - *For example, you could create a user for your web site and grant it access to only the pertinent tables used by the web site.*
  - *One benefit of using multiple users is you can more easily trace the source of the compromise in the event it happens.*